# Using a read method in my android app

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

So I created an application where I have a GUI class. This application will listen for 2 incoming strings from another application i created when a togglebutton is activated. What i simply cant wrap my head around is how to read the incoming bytes and pass them through my code back to where they are used in my GUI class. Hope anyone is able to help.

When I send my two strings i get the bytes of both then send the first, get the bytes of a "%" string, send that as a seperator and then send the second.

```
public void ListenForAddress(View view)
{
    on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if(on)
    {
        Address address = reciever.RecieveObject();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Screen3.class);
        String adressStr = address.Address;
        intent.putExtra("ADRESS_MESSAGE", adressStr);
        String postalcodeStr = address.Postalcode;
        intent.putExtra("POSTALCODE_MESSAGE", postalcodeStr);
        intent.putExtra("ONE", 1);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        reciever.closeReception();
    }   
}
```

As you can see I create a receiver and with that I call a method called RecieveObject() that method looks like the following.

```
public Address RecieveObject() 
{
    accThread = new AcceptThread();
    accThread.start();
    return null;
}
```

Next step is the thread that creates the connection and starts the managing thread

```
public class AcceptThread extends Thread {


public AcceptThread() {
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
    try {
    tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Server", MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmServerSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
        // If a connection was accepted
        if (socket != null) {
            mConnSock = new manageConnectedSocket(socket);
            mConnSock.read();
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The final step is the thread handling the data

```
public class manageConnectedSocket extends Thread {

public manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    mmSocket = socket;
    InputStream tmpIn = null;

    try {
        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) { }

    mmInStream = tmpIn;
}

public Address read() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes; 
    Address address = new Address("", "");
    int count = 0;

    while(count<2)
    {
        try {
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            if(count==0)
            {
                address.Address = new String(buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                address.Postalcode = new String(buffer);
            }
            buffer = new byte[1024];

        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return address;
}

}
```

Comment: Hehe i know it might be a bit too much but had a hard time seeing where i should cut down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending the address and the postal code, send a seperator between them. It could be any character which will never appear in neither the address nor the postal code, or even a sequence of characters, to be extra safe. For example: `!@#@!`. *You should send the data in one call to `write`.*

So you're sending the address this way:

```
String data = address + "!@#@!" + postalCode;
byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
socket.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

When reading the address, you shouldn't call a method which retrieves the address, because it will block your thread. Instead, call a method from the connection thread when the address is ready. Start the therad this way:

```
manageConnectedSocket(socket).start();
```

In it's `run` method, read the strings:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024]; //You can make this array larger, if you think it won't have enough space to contain some addresses.
    socket.getInputStream().read(data); //This may block the thread, if no data is currently available.
    String strings = new String(data);
    int seperatorIndex = strings.indexOf("!@#@!");
    String addressStr = strings.substring(0, seperatorIndex);
    String postalCode = strings.substring(seperatorIndex + 5); //5 is the length of "!@#@!".
    Address address = new Address(addressStr, postalCode);
    makeUseOfAddress(address); //Show it to the user, for example. Remember it's called from this thread, so if you want to interact with your UI, you have to run the interacting code on the UI thread and not here.
}
```